# How can i pass asp.net server control type in function?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I am writing a function in my class file which connects to the db and loads the data. I want to pass a query, asp.net control type and control id to the function, such that when i call the function , it can load the data based on control type(where i will be writing a switch case for each control type). Some thing like this :

```
public static string LoadData(string qry, Controltype, controlId)
{


string connstring = "......";
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
con.Open();
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(qry, connstring);
dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
switch(controltype)
{
 case DropDownList:
      ......
      ......
 break;

case GridView:
      ......
      ......
break;
}
```

Can anybody tell me how can i pass Controltype and controlId in this function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadData(ddlList, ddlList.ID);
    LoadData(chkBxList, chkBxList.ID);
}

void LoadData(WebControl control, string id)
{
    string typeName = control.GetType().Name;
    switch (typeName)
    {
        case "DropDownList":
                //do something here
            break;
        case "CheckBoxList":
            //do something here
            break;
    }
}
```

I have one CheckBoxList and DropDownList in my HTML code as below:

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkBxList" runat="server">
  </asp:CheckBoxList>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" runat="server"/>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Sajoshi, This seems to be working. But a small change, the above function LoadData is in a separate class file, so i am facing a problem in adding items to control. I need to write control.Items.Add(list). But it does'nt give intellisense. Can i know an other way of adding items to list. Or why it does'nt allow me to add items? I guess control is not exactly acting as a dropdownlist.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
DropDownList Ll = new DropDownList();
Ll = (DropDownList)control;
```

Comment: What's that have to do with the OP's problem?